# Can I hold processing of Azure Service Queue messages by X number of hours/days

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-iot-hub, polly, circuit-breaker

I have a use case: I am processing Service Bus queue and pushing data into IoTHub.

There is a case when IoTHub quota exceeded for a day, in this case I am generating exception and throwing messages into dead letter.

Question is, Is there is anything available where I can hold processing of entire queue for some hour and next day when IoT quota available, my messages starts processing again?

something like Circuit breaker stuff?

Comment: Circuit breaker will not hold your messages. It is just a proxy which sits between your application and the downstream system. It prevents future outgoing request if the downstream service is treated inaccessible (temporarily).

Comment: @PeterCsala. my thinking was also same on this. Thanks for confirming! Is there anything fit in my use case?

Comment: you can send the schedule message, example: long seq = await sender.ScheduleMessageAsync(message, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(24)

Comment: How many percentage of your messages are being rejected due to daily limit?

Comment: @PeterCsala, it could be any number (1-1000), but how to schedule messages? already messages are in queue? I am do  `AbandonMessageAsync` to re-process again or `DeadLetterMessageAsync` to move to dead letter.

Comment: I can't control up-stream system which sending messages to the queue. I want control from client who is consuming messages ?

Answer (score 0):

We can perform such kind of related operations using **Locks**. We have an operation called **[PeeKLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement#peeklock)** using which we can perform holding type operation.